# Webview show old user Data after Logout

Tags: android, webview

In my application using webview show user data after login, but once logout from application and login with new user in webview. It shows old user data instead of new. Already clean cookies, session and database before the login,  but it's not working.

Here is my login page code

```
public class Login_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private EditText et_username, et_password;
    private List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> categoriesLink = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ProgressDialog prDialog;
    private CheckBox saveLoginCheckBox;
    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    private Boolean saveLogin;
    private DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
    private String txt_username, txt_password;
    private String pre_username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");


        /* .. NewworkonMain ThradException error solution*/

       if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(Login_Activity.this);
        setcontent();
    }

    private void setcontent() {
        et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        saveLoginCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.saveLoginCheckBox);
        loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

        // Spinner element
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        //  spinner.setPrompt("Service Name");
        saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean(AppConstant.PREF_SAVE_LOGIN, false);
        if (saveLogin == true) {
            et_username.setText(loginPreferences.getString(AppConstant.PREF_USER_NAME, ""));
            // et_password.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password1", ""));
            saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        // Login Button
        Button btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Internet Connection
                if (!Common.isInternetOn(Login_Activity.this)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                // Null Value Validation
                int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                if (pos == 0 || pos == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please add service name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty((et_username.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please add username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty((et_password.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please add password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                pre_username = et_username.getText().toString();
                //    String passoed1 = et_password.getText().toString();

                if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean(AppConstant.PREF_SAVE_LOGIN, true);
                    loginPrefsEditor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_USER_NAME, pre_username);
                    loginPrefsEditor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_SELECTED_SERVICE, spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    // loginPrefsEditor.putString("password1", passoed1);
                    loginPrefsEditor.commit();
                } else {
                    loginPrefsEditor.clear();
                    loginPrefsEditor.commit();
                }

                // add http logic
                if (categories != null && categories.size() > 0) {
                    selectedPath = categoriesLink.get(pos);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedPath)) {
                        if (!selectedPath.toLowerCase().contains("http"))
                            selectedPath = "http://" + selectedPath;
                        new SaveAppData().execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //Add Button
        Button btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, AddServiceName_Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 999);
            }
        });
        checkPermission();
    }

    private void fillUpSpinner() {
        categories.clear();
        categoriesLink.clear();
        List<ServiceDetails> serviceList = databaseHandler.getAllServiceList();
        for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++) {
            ServiceDetails serviceDetail = serviceList.get(i);
            categories.add(serviceDetail.getName());
            categoriesLink.add(serviceDetail.getUrl());
        }
        if (categories.size() > 0) {
            categories.add(0, "Select service name");
            categoriesLink.add(0, "");
        } else {
            categories.add("Add service name");
            categoriesLink.add("");
        }

        if (dataAdapter == null) {
            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            if (saveLogin) {
                String selectedService = loginPreferences.getString("selected_service", "");
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedService)) {
                    int pos = categories.indexOf(selectedService);
                    spinner.setSelection(pos);
                }
            }
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        } else {
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 999) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             /*   String serName = data.getStringExtra("serName");
                String serUrl = data.getStringExtra("serUrl");*/
                fillUpSpinner();
                /*categories.clear();
                categoriesLink.clear();*/
                /*categories.add(0, serName);
                categoriesLink.add(0, serUrl);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner.setSelection(0);*/
            } else {
                if (!saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    // spinner.setSelection(0);
                    et_username.setText("");
                    et_password.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    String selectedPath = null;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        // String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        //   Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    // SaveAppData Web API Method
    public class SaveAppData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String str = "A";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            prDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_Activity.this);
            prDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            prDialog.show();
        }

        Response responseValue;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String device_id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

            // String url = "http://192.168.0.122:5000/api/Login/SaveAppData?deviceID=" + device_id + "&deviceType=" + str;
            if (!selectedPath.endsWith("/")) {
                selectedPath = selectedPath + "/";
            }

            SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(AppConstant.PREF_SELECTED_PATH, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_URI_SELECTEDPATH, selectedPath);
            editor.commit();

            String url = (selectedPath + "api/Login/SaveAppData?deviceID=" + device_id + "&deviceType=" + str);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            //WebAPI.PostData(url, jsonObject.toString());
            responseValue = WebAPI.PostDataWithStatusCode(Login_Activity.this, url, jsonObject.toString());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
           /* if(prDialog!=null){
                prDialog.dismiss();
            }*/
            try {
                if (responseValue != null) {
                    int code = responseValue.code();
                    String str = responseValue.body().string();

                    if (code == 200) {
                        parseResponseAndSaveDefaultURL(str);
                        new AuthenticateUser().execute();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please enter valid Host Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please enter valid Host Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    // get WebURL from SaveAppData Response
    private void parseResponseAndSaveDefaultURL(String str) {
        try {
            String res = str;
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
            String url = jsonObject.getString("value");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
                SharedPreferences pref_token = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login_Activity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_token.edit();
                editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_RESPONCE_DEFAULT_URL, url);
                editor.commit();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // AuthenticateUser Web API Method
    public class AuthenticateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           /* prDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_Activity.this);
            prDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            prDialog.show();*/
            txt_username = et_username.getText().toString();
            txt_password = et_password.getText().toString();
        }

        Response responseValue;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String device_id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("username", txt_username);
                jsonObject.put("password", txt_password);
                jsonObject.put("deviceID", device_id);
                /*String response = WebAPI.PostData("http://192.168.0.122:5000//api/Login/AuthenticateUser", jsonObject.toString());*/
                if (!selectedPath.endsWith("/")) {
                    selectedPath = selectedPath + "/";
                }
                //      String response = WebAPI.PostData(Login_Activity.this,selectedPath+"api/Login/AuthenticateUser",jsonObject.toString());
                responseValue = WebAPI.PostDataWithStatusCode(Login_Activity.this, selectedPath + "api/Login/AuthenticateUser", jsonObject.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (prDialog != null) {
                prDialog.dismiss();
            }
            try {
                if (responseValue != null) {
                    int code = responseValue.code();
                    String str = responseValue.body().string();
                    if (code == 200) {

                       CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Login_Activity.this);
                       CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                       cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
                       cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
                       cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
                       clearCacheFromWebView();

                       WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Login_Activity.this).clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();
                       WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Login_Activity.this).clearUsernamePassword();
                       WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Login_Activity.this).clearFormData();
                       deleteDatabase("webview.db");
                       deleteDatabase("webviewCache,db");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, Home_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                        SharedPreferences pref_token = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login_Activity.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_token.edit();
                        editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_RESPONCE_TOKEN, str);
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please enter valid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login_Activity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_USER_NAME, txt_username);
            editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_PASSWORD, txt_password);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are determining current user from SharedPreferences values.So, you have to make changes to the SharedPreferences before you start HomeActivity.

Hope it helped you. Thanks.

**Update (Code)**

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (prDialog != null) {
            prDialog.dismiss();
        }
        try {
            if (responseValue != null) {
                int code = responseValue.code();
                String str = responseValue.body().string();
                if (code == 200) {

                   CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Login_Activity.this);
                   CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                   cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
                   cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
                   cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
                   clearCacheFromWebView();

                   WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Login_Activity.this).clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();
                   WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Login_Activity.this).clearUsernamePassword();
                   WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Login_Activity.this).clearFormData();
                   deleteDatabase("webview.db");
                   deleteDatabase("webviewCache,db");

                    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login_Activity.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_USER_NAME, txt_username);
                    editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_PASSWORD, txt_password);
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, Home_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                    SharedPreferences pref_token = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login_Activity.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_token.edit();
                    editor.putString(AppConstant.PREF_RESPONCE_TOKEN, str);
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Please enter valid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: before logout I clear all store SharedPreferences value & in debug get the valid username and password but data should display old user

Comment: @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (prDialog != null) {
                prDialog.dismiss();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home_Activity.this, Login_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            finish();
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry for late reply. What do you mean by this code? If it is the new onPostExecute(), i didn't see the required change in it. Otherwise please update the question with new onPostExecute()

Comment: this code means before the logout I already clear all data in SharedPreferences...     also try with this but not working .........SharedPreferences preferences =getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
             editor.clear();
             editor.commit();

Comment: already try with that still not working ..                                                                   thanks for the helping me ..

Comment: Then it may be something with your Home Activity